# Fatal Error Activating CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

We had this issue activating CiviCRM

```
Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/capitaleventscom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 462

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/home/capitalevents/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/home/capitalevents/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/capitaleventscom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 462
```

then followed by this when using a fresh download:

```
Could not extract file from archive. civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/themes/dark/img/files/big/..png
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Got enough disk space on your server?

Comment: Solution for the first error here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/38122/8440

Answer (score 1):

A warning like Cannot redeclare class CRM_Core_ClassLoader can indicate that all is not good in the civicrm.settings.php file, such as incorrect paths. not quite the same warning you have but may be a useful pointer

Answer (score 1):

In the civicrm.settings.php file which should be located in 
`wp-content\uploads\civicrm`, search for $civicrm_root variable and check if it is directing to the directory where you installed CiviCRM plugin. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but found it was due to having an old copy of the directory *civicrm* in the wp-content/uploads folder. When I deleted this whole folder the plugin activated normally.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the 2nd error related to "civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/themes/dark/img/files/big/..png" simply unzip downloaded civicrm file on local machine; look for the file "..png" and delete it. There should be 4 of them - one each in dark/default themes in big/small directories.

After deleting these files, create a zip with remaining file and upload to your wordpress using Install Plugin page.