# Fails to open ClassLoader.php file

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I've installed the plugin successfully, but when I go visit the CiviCRM page in the backend, I get the following error:

Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/capitaleventscom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 462

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/home/capitalevents/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/home/capitalevents/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/capitaleventscom/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 462

I've tried but couldn't figure out anything. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file `civicrm.settings.php` the variable `$civicrm_root` is defined. It should point to the directory where you installed the CiviCRM plugin. If it has the wrong value it causes the reported error.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the @Kainuk answer. Here is what i did today to solve the same error.
In your civicrm.settings.php if you have

```
require_once 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
```

Change it by adding "civicrm_root" variable

```
require_once $civicrm_root . '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
```

This is assuming that somewhere in that file, you have already set the "$civicrm_root" variable to point to your civiCRM install directory such as

```
$civicrm_root = '/var/www/html/drupal-root/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core';
```