# ERROR Upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.28 - Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php):

Tags: upgrade

I am on Joomla version 3.8.2 with Php 7. I tried to upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7.28 but I received and error message (I didn't capture it) that it could not unzip the file because I have php 7. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the administration panel as I am getting a blank screen.

These are the error messages:

```
Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/pastoral99/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 462

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/home/pastoral99/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm:/home/pastoral99/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages:.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/pastoral99/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php on line 462
```

Please HELP!

Comment: Hi @Tee, does the file /home/pastoral99/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php exist and is it readable by the apache server?

Comment: Hi Kainuk, ClassLoader.php does not exist in this directory. Looks like some files were not installed during the upgrade.

Comment: Looks you have found the solution, I wrap it up in an answer.

Comment: i reread your comment and unzipping the file worked. i am now able to access my joomla admin area. i have many civicrm errors but ill try to figure those out and hopefully get it back up and running again. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file `ClassLoader.php` is on the file system. The location for Joomla is:

```
../administrator/components/com_ci‌vicrm/civicrm/CRM/Co‌​re/ClassLoader.php
```

Part of an upgrade procedure is to remove the old version and unpack the new version in the same place. If the unpacking fails the above error is shown.

Another reason for the same error can be the wrong value of `$civicrm_root` in the `civicrm.settings.php` file. More information in question [Fails to open ClassLoader.php file](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20677/fails-to-open-classloader-php-file) .

Comment: Thanks for your help! Another question, since the failed installation is the culprit and likely the reason I can't access the Joomla administration panel, how can I reinstall outside of Joomla?

Comment: I am not an expert on Joomla, but if you can try to unzip the Joomla installation files in  the `../administrator/components/com_ci‌vicrm/civicrm` directory.

Comment: Actually, I need to install or uninstall and reinstall CiviCRM. The failed CiviCRM installation is preventing me from accessing the Joomla admin panel.